# Ajuda com where no Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller

Oi, pessoal queria uma ajuda de vocês em um where.

No meu sistema está assim, estou na página galeria de fotos do Empreendimento( id=1 ), 
nesta página eu posso cadastrar as fotos do mês/ano do empreendimento ( as etapas da obra ).
Quando eu cadastro as fotos cria um botão na mesma pagina com titulo de mês/ano ( Ex: Dezembro/2014 ) e se tiver em Janeiro ele vai cadastrar as fotos de Janeiro/2015.
E quando eu clico neste botão é para abrir um modal com as fotos referentes somente àquele mês/ano ( Dezembro/2014 ) do empreendimento( id=1).

Eu consegui fazer isto com Ajax passar os valores e me retornar as foto, mas agora estou com um probleminha, quando eu clico no botão ( Dezembro/2014 ), ele abre o modal e puxa todas as fotos dos empreendimento com o id=1, vamos dizer que eu cadastrei ( 8 fotos no Dezembro/2014 ) e ( 6 fotos Janeiro/2015 ) ele deveria puxar só as 8 fotos no Dezembro/2014 e não as 14 fotos.

Tela empreendimento:

[image: Tela do empreendimento]

Banco:

[image: Como esta no banco]

Código Ajax:

```
$('.requerAjax').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var resultado = $(this).attr('rel').split('/');
var mes = resultado[0];
var ano = resultado[1];
var categorias_id = resultado[2];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/empreendimento/fotos-ajax",
    data: { mes: mes, ano: ano, categorias_id: categorias_id }, 
    datatype: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(".carregando").show();
    },
    success: function(result){       
        $(".carregando").hide();
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {                
            html += "<img src=" + result[i].imagem + " alt=''>";            
        }
        $( ".modal-body .gallery" ).html(html); 
    }
});
```

});

Código Controller recebendo do ajax:

```
public function postFotosAjax() {
    // $mesAno = Input::all();
    $mes = Input::get('mes');
    $ano = Input::get('ano');
    $id = Input::get('categorias_id');

    if(Request::ajax()){
        $FotosMesAno = DB::table('fotos')
        ->select('mes', 'ano', 'imagem')
        ->where('mes', '=', $mes) // Tem que ser um MES.
        ->where('ano', '=', $ano, 'AND') // Tem que ser um ANO.
        ->where('categorias_id', '=', $id, 'AND') // Tem que ser um ID DO EMPREENDIMENTO.
        ->get();
        return Response::json($FotosMesAno);
    }
}
```

Exploro como dele ficar cada tela:

1. Empreendimento 1

   - Dezembro/2014 ( Fotos cadastrada 8 )
   - Janeiro/2015 ( Fotos cadastrada 6 )
   - Fevereiro/2015 ( Fotos cadastrada 12 )
   - Março/2015 ( Fotos cadastrada 10 )
   - Abril/2015 ( Fotos cadastrada 8 )
2. Empreendimento 2

   - Dezembro/2014 ( Fotos cadastrada 20 )
   - Janeiro/2015 ( Fotos cadastrada 18 )
   - Fevereiro/2015 ( Fotos cadastrada 10 )
   - Março/2015 ( Fotos cadastrada 19 )

Sera que alguém pode me ajudar, a puxar as foto de cada mês/ano?

Comment: Você esta usando `OR categorias_id`, mas deve utilizar `AND`.

Comment: São todos AND..

Comment: Realmente era só colocar AND no lugar o OR.
**_OBRIGADO_** Vinícius e Vagner.

Comment: Pode postar o código como texto e não como imagem ?

Comment: @gmsantos coloquei o código enviando via ajax e retornando do controller para o ajax.